# "The certificate for this website is invalid" after upload to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, certificate

I uploaded my Rails application to `Heroku`, bought a domain name `mysite.com` on `Site5` and pointed it to my Heroku application URL. I can normally access my site on Heroku when I type www.mysite.com and everything works.

The problem is that before my site opens, I receive a warning that the certificate for this website is invalid and that some other site is pretending to be my site. This looks bad if a customer comes to my site and sees that warning and needs to accept their information "will be at risk". How can I avoid this message?

Here is the screenshot how it looks in Safari:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Heroku provides a wildcard SSL certificate covering all herokuapp.com subdomains. This will only be valid, of course, when accessing your app via its herokuapp.com subdomain.

If you need SSL for your custom domain, you need to acquire your own certificate for that domain and pay Heroku ($20/mo) to use that certificate for your application.

If you don't need SSL, verify your code isn't redirecting HTTP to HTTPS requests. This isn't something Heroku normally does by itself; any forced-secure transit is most likely coming from your application.

See Heroku KB: [SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint)

Comment: Thank you. In my browser I see that my code redirects HTTP to HTTPS requests. I don't need SSL at the moment. How can configure my app not to use SSL?

Comment: There are many ways to make Rails force SSL, so knowing nothing about your application, it's hard to say. For the most likely option, make sure `config.force_ssl` in your production environment file isn't set to true, and that you're not calling `force_ssl` anywhere.

Comment: In `config/environments/production.rb` I have a line `config.force_ssl = true`. Will check that later this evening when I try to upload again. Tnx!